# 500 Internal Server Error when uploading GeoJSON to Azure Maps Data Service

Tags: geojson, azure-maps

I always receive 500 Internal Service Error

POST: https://atlas.microsoft.com/mapData/upload?subscription-key=&api-version=1.0&dataFormat=geojson

Sample data:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
     {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [
           [
             [
               -122.13393688201903,
               47.63829579223815
             ],
             [
               -122.13389128446579,
               47.63782047131512
             ],
             [
               -122.13240802288054,
               47.63783312249837
             ],
             [
               -122.13238388299942,
               47.63829037035086
             ],
             [
               -122.13393688201903,
               47.63829579223815
             ]
           ]
         ]
       },
       "properties": {
         "geometryId": "1"
       }
     },
     {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [
           [
             [
               -122.13374376296996,
               47.63784758098976
             ],
             [
               -122.13277012109755,
               47.63784577367854
             ],
             [
               -122.13314831256866,
               47.6382813338708
             ],
             [
               -122.1334782242775,
               47.63827591198201
             ],
             [
               -122.13374376296996,
               47.63784758098976
             ]
           ]
         ]
       },
       "properties": {
         "geometryId": "2",
         "validityTime": {
           "expiredTime": "2019-01-15T00:00:00",
           "validityPeriod": [
             {
               "startTime": "2019-01-08T01:00:00",
               "endTime": "2019-01-08T17:00:00",
               "recurrenceType": "Daily",
               "recurrenceFrequency": 1,
               "businessDayOnly": true
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

Need help

Comment: Looks like there was an outage earlier. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Are you still blocked? Can you try now and update?